# Is application/x-javascript in .htaccess even for externaly load java scripts?

Tags: javascript, .htaccess

I got this line in .htaccess:

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
```

It should be for compressing js, but I would like to know if it is even for external javascripts loaded like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" async>
    var leady_track_key="jReps29OXPLsAueX";
    var leady_track_server=document.location.protocol+"//t.leady.cz/";
    (function(){
        var l=document.createElement("script");l.type="text/javascript";l.async=true;
        l.src=leady_track_server+leady_track_key+"/L.js";
        var s=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(l,s);
    })();
</script>
```

Thx for your help

Comment: That's inline JS, and so you'd need to deflate your HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`AddOutputFilterByType` ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#accessfilename)) activates a filter for any page with a certain mime type that is *server by this server*.

To answer your question: No, for externally loaded javascript files, that do not reside on your server, this does not take effect. It does not take effect on inline javascript on your html pages, as these files have a mime-type `text/html`.

The directive `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript` only works on files with the mime-type `application/x-javascript`, which is probably files ending with `.js` loaded from your server.